# How to remove empty rows from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am populating a `JComboBox` which contains five items. When I click on the drop down box, instead of showing five, rows it's showing 20 rows; from sixth row, it's showing empty. How can I make the drop down to have exactly same number of rows as total number of items.

Comment: read the api doc, you'll find a method to configure the size :-)

Comment: How you add the data to combobox?

Comment: Filter out the blank rows before putting them into the JComboBox.

Comment: How are you populating the `JComboBox`? Just adding 5 items to the JComboBox means that only 5 rows will show. You must somehow be adding more than 5 items to your combobox. Post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: Yeah i got the reason. I was initializing the jcombobox as               new JComboBox(envComboBox);  where envComboBox is of size 20. Now i am  adding one by one and its working fine.                                   Thank You everyone for the replies.